# Rails and favicon issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, favicon

So I created a 16x16 favicon.ico file and placed it in my public/assets area. I also double downed and put it in my app/assets/image section.

I added and the image will not load up in Chrome, but it seems to load up in Firefox and Safari for me. That said, it won't load up in any of my friend's browsers. I also tried with or without the /.

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>
```

So I tried

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="cameronswiggett.com/favicon.ico" />
```

and same results.

I went to config/enviroments/production and made

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

the thing that confuses is me when I go to www.mysite.com/favicon.ico I see a broken image. So, obviously something is wrong but I am at a loss. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting the favicon directly in the public directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did it on my apps :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

Here my favicon is in /public/img folder, it works for me so it may works for you, I added the two tags to make sure it works everywhere